# how to calculate next 30 days from current date (MySQL)?

Tags: mysql

i want to get next 30 days record from current date.
any suggestion or tip will be appreciated.

```
  SELECT end_date FROM master_data
        WHERE end_date BETWEEN DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL 30 DAY) AND CURRENT_DATE();
```

Comment: You've already done `DATE_SUB`, just do `DATE_ADD` instead.

Comment: done but not getting result

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need `DATE_ADD` not `DATE_SUB`, because the next 30 days will be between current date and current date + 30:

```
SELECT end_date 
FROM master_data
WHERE end_date BETWEEN CURRENT_DATE()
                   AND DATE_ADD(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL 30 DAY) ;
```

- [**Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/17163fc/3)